# How to get data from Server using ID in Android

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am writing a Native Android App in which i am using PHP MYSQL to get data from server

In this [Appointment List] i am allowing user to Reschedule an Appointment, but whenever i do tap on item getting blank form, in short not getting data for that particular appointment which i have clicked in a List.

**Question**

*How to show data in a form using AppointmentID ?*

Below i am showing all required code written by me [Client & Server Side both]

**UpcomingActivity.java:**

```
        @Override
        public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
            int menuItemIndex = item.getItemId();
            String[] menuItems = Cmd;
            String CmdName = menuItems[menuItemIndex];
            // Check Event Command
            if ("Cancel".equals(CmdName)) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(UpcomingActivity.this,"Selected Cancel",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();           
            }
            else if ("Reschedule".equals(CmdName)) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(UpcomingActivity.this,"Selected Update",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                String sAppointmentID = MyArrList.get(info.position).get("UserID").toString();                      
                Log.d(tag, "sAppointmentID :: " + sAppointmentID);

                Intent newActivity = new Intent(UpcomingActivity.this, UpdateActivity.class);
                newActivity.putExtra("UserID", sAppointmentID);                     
                startActivity(newActivity);
            }             
            return true;
        }
```

**UpdateActivity.java:**

```
            public void showInfo()
            {
                final TextView tAppointmentID = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtUsername);
                final TextView tType = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtName);
                final TextView tDate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
                final TextView tTime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtTel);

                Button btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
                Button btnCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
                String url = "http://10.0.2.2/appointments/getByMemberID.php";

                Intent intent= getIntent();
                final String AppointmentID = intent.getStringExtra("AppointmentID");
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sAppointmentID", AppointmentID));

                String resultServer  = getHttpPost(url,params);
                String strAppointmentID = "";               
                String strType = "";
                String strDate = "";
                String strTime = "";

                JSONObject c;
                try {
                    c = new JSONObject(resultServer);

                    strAppointmentID = c.getString("UserID");
                    Log.d(TAG, "String strAppointmentID" + strAppointmentID);
                    strType = c.getString("Type");
                    Log.d(TAG, "String strType" + strType);
                    strDate = c.getString("Date");
                    Log.d(TAG, "String strDate" + strDate);
                    strTime = c.getString("Time");
                    Log.d(TAG, "String strTime" + strTime);

                    if(!strAppointmentID.equals(""))
                    {
                        tAppointmentID.setText(strAppointmentID);
                        tType.setText(strType);
                        tDate.setText(strDate);
                        tTime.setText(strTime);
                    }   
                    else
                    {
                        tAppointmentID.setText("-");
                        tType.setText("-");
                        tDate.setText("-");
                        tTime.setText("-"); 
                        btnSave.setEnabled(false);
                        btnCancel.requestFocus();
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }   
            }
```

Comment: first confirm that the php is ok. For this, enter the id manually inside **getByMemberID.php** and load it from a web browser. 10.0.2.2/appointments/getByMemberID.php

Comment: Please be careful about SQL injection attacks. Your current code is wide open, because you directly enter user input ($_POST) into your queries. Google it - it is quick to fix if you use PHP's `mysqli` package (or other alternatives to `mysql`), or else perform some checks on the input before using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. first of all make sure that you have valid `AppointmentID` and `UserId`and
2. in `UpcomingActivity.java` at method `onContextItemSelected` you are not providing `AppointmentID` instead you are only providing `UserID` to the `Intend`
3. List but in `Updateactivity` at method `showData` you are requesting `intent.getStringExtra("AppointmentID")` which is invaild.

so your update your `UpcomingActivity.java` should look like this

```
 public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
        int menuItemIndex = item.getItemId();
        String[] menuItems = Cmd;
        String CmdName = menuItems[menuItemIndex];
        // Check Event Command
        if ("Cancel".equals(CmdName)) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(UpcomingActivity.this,"Selected Cancel",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();           
        }
        else if ("Reschedule".equals(CmdName)) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(UpcomingActivity.this,"Selected Update",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            String sAppointmentID = MyArrList.get(info.position).get("UserID").toString();                      
            Log.d(tag, "sAppointmentID :: " + sAppointmentID);

            Intent newActivity = new Intent(UpcomingActivity.this, UpdateActivity.class);
            newActivity.putExtra("UserID", sAppointmentID);
            newActivity.putExtra("AppointmentID", MyArrList.get(info.position).get("AppointmentID").toString());// <== here                     
            startActivity(newActivity);
        }             
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: thanks, but now i am not able to update data, please check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18606478/how-to-update-data-using-php-mysql-in-android

Answer (score 1):

I noticed a couple of issues (might be typos, but I prefer to ask anyway):

- You are calling a `getByMemberID.php`, but you have not included its source code in the question - you do have such service, right? :)
- In the `onContextItemSelected` you are starting the `UpdateActivity` and pass `UserID` as extra. But in the `showInfo` method of that activity you are trying to get `AppointmentID` from the intent's extras, so it is not processing any data.

Answer (score 0):

1) Try weather your PHP code is working fine or not...
You can do that by running directly on server and passing UserId and appoinmentId as a parameter by ?

For eg....   www.abc.com?sUserId=123?sAppointmentID=456

See weather it's showing you proper output.

2) you are calling getByMemberID.php but you have specified code of it but you are not passing "AppointmentID" for that also check with php code weather you are retriving it ??

3) On call of updateData.php in UpdateActivity.java: you are not providing "AppointmentID" but you are retriving it in php code it will get null value by default which will be  an error ofcourse